# how to plot a histogram with nan?

Tags: python

I want to plot an histogram with data containing nan value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist([nan, 0.038173986947958476], 100)
plt.show()
```

It gives me this error:

```
    data=[0.0453100745718402, nan]
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.isnan()` to choose only valid entries. For a given array `A` you can choose the valid entries using `A[~np.isnan(A)]` and plot the histogram with `plt.hist(A[~np.isnan(A)], 100)`.

(I think the `nan` entries need to be `np.nan` for this to work though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import numpy as np to use np.nan
But still you can not plot that properly because np.nan is out of range.
You can add something like range=[0,5] to the hist method maybe it will show what you want but I think it’s better to clean the data first to eliminate nans